# Error in the Navigation.InsertPageBefore method in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

This is my login screen (and up to here everything is ok)
[image]

The method is linked to the button with the icon in the ContentPage.ToolbarItems

```
async void OnLogoutButtonClicked(object Sender, EventArgs e, Session session)
        {
            App.IsUserLoggedIn = false;
            if (session != null)
            {
                session.Dispose();
            }

            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new LoginPage(), this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

[image]

This is the new instance of LoginPage ... in the circle you notice the Hamburger Menu as if my Login Page had become a Master-Detail Page ... I tried different ways to get back to that LoginPage but it does not change anything ... where am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: I guess you should dispose your session and set the `App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage()` instead. Did you tried it?

Comment: Yes but if I press back button on device/emulator the application return to the screen where I called the logout method

Comment: Excuse me, I mean `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());`

Comment: Idem if I press back button on device/emulator the application return to the screen where I called the logout method

Comment: But the hamburger menu icon does vanish?

Comment: Yes,your method it's right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167279/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-riccardo-pezzolati).